# Creating a GMail Hyperlink "Mailto?" to Multiple Recipients

Tags: email, gmail, gmail-imap

I am attempting to create a hyperlink mailto for a google mail to multiple recipients using the following string:
https://mail.google.com/mail/&view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&to=recipient1@emailprovider.com,%20https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&to=recipient2@emailprovider.com

... only when I test it, it drafts a gmail message to recipient2 while completely bypassing recipient1, and a partial, incomplete string: "recipient1@emailprovider.com, https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm"

Further, my ULTIMATE goal is to add a 3rd recipient.  Again, the result is a draft opened with only recipient2 and the same incomplete string.

What am I missing??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mention the multiple email receipts in the parameter 'to' with semicolon as delimiter. Please check my example link below: (I've tested it and it's working for me)

> to=recipient1@emailprovider.com;recipient2@emailprovider.com;recipient3@emailprovider.com;recipient4@emailprovider.com

**Full example:**

> https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&to=recipient1@emailprovider.com;recipient2@emailprovider.com;recipient3@emailprovider.com;recipient4@emailprovider.com

Comment: Many, MANY, thanks!  It did work ... though I did notice one other slight modification between my string (https://mail.google.com/mail/&view= ...), which simply opened my email to my inbox with no draft), and yours (https://mail.google.com/mail/?view= ...), which actually performed what I wanted.  Again, MANY thanks! :-D

Comment: Remembering back to a previous post, when searching for an answer to this question, also found how to include a pre-filled subject for this same draft! (https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&to=recipient1@emailprovider.com;recipient2@emailprovider.com;recipient3@emailprovider.com&su=Enter Your Subject Here) Whoo-hoo! :-D

Comment: Yes!  Thank you for your help - it was perfect, EXACTLY what I needed! :-)

Comment: Super. Nice to hear :)